# Locking execution within CompletableFuture

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I need to post-process result of `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` execution to get intermediate result.
My code looks following

```
var executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                       Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(),
                       Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                       2L,
                       TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                       // size of queue has to be restricted since Java Heap Space could  appear; 
                       // default size of queue is Integer.MAX_VALUE
                       new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(10_000_000));
var resultOfBatch = new ResultOfBatch();
var lock = new ReentrantLock();
// usually `settings.getRuns()` could be up to 1_000_000_000 runs
LongStream.range(0, settings.getRuns())
    .forEach(l -> {
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(task, executor)

                // collecting result per run to resultOfBatch (mainly simple operations like adding values to primitives)
                .thenApply(resultPerRun -> {
                    lock.lock();
                    return resultOfBatch.addResultPerBatch(resultPerRun);
                })

                // the idea in logging partial result - ex.,every 10K passes
                .thenAccept(resultPerBatch -> {
                    if (resultPerBatch.getRuns() % 10_000 == 0) {
                        // log intermediate result of execution
                        resultOfBatch.reset();
                    }
                    lock.unlock();
                });
    });
```

In a result I'm facing with `java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException` on `.thenAccept(resultPerBatch -> {` line

Seems like I'm using `lock` in wrong way but I cannot figure out how to avoid this kind of exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no guarantee that the `Function` passed to `thenApply` and the `Consumer` passed to `thenAccept` will execute on the same thread.

In this case, there is no need to separate them into separate steps:

```java
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> l, executor)
        .thenAcceptAsync(resultPerRun -> {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                var resultPerBatch = resultOfBatch.addResultPerBatch(resultPerRun);
                if (resultPerBatch.getRuns() % 10_000 == 0) {
                    System.out.println(resultPerBatch.getRuns());
                    resultOfBatch.reset();
                }
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }, executor);
```

However, it is probably a better idea to process this data in batches rather than trying to create so many threads. This will ultimately either run out of memory, out of available native threads, or reject work because the queue is full.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion!
And yeah, you was right - I'm faced with memory issue (like Java heap space and stack memory is out). I'm going to solve this via applying batching. But - I need to shutdown executor between starts batch chunks in order to release resources

Comment: You should be able to reuse the executor. Releasing resources only to immediately reacquire them won’t have much benefit. What would be more helpful is slowing down the rate of adding tasks to the queue. I can recommend an asynchronous streaming framework with built in back pressure such as Akka Streams.

Comment: In my case, I observe that when 27+ million threads are finished, a memory leak starts and a occurs java heap space. But if I shutdown executor once per 20 million finished thread, looks all OK and used memory is going down. Definitely it will occur some delay in execution (shutdown and start executor again) but I can ignore that.

Ideally will be nice to use Redis for that but unfortunately I have limitations about Redis usages